# Excel vba: Insert cells/row down without moving selected ones

Tags: excel, vba

`xldown` inserts and moves the selected cells/row down.
ie `Range(*****).Insert Shift:=xlDown`

But what i want instead to do is to keep the selected row as it as and shift the below rows down.

Can anyone help on writting vba for this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For a single column using

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("A1:A10")
rng1.Cells(1).Offset(rng1.Cells.Count).Resize(rng1.Cells.Count, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

would insert cells from `A11:A20`